# Initializing a variable that will hold an internal class

Tags: c#, class, initialization, internal

I have a class called `CollsionForm` that is an XML class definition.
When I try to intialize a variable:

```
CollisionForm collision;
```

and reference it later in the method like this:

```
return collision;
```

I get an error that it may not be initialized first.

How do I initialize the variable `collisionform` 
like I would if I did: `String str = new String.empty` ?

I tried `CollisionForm collision = new CollisionForm;` 
But that gives the error:

> Cannot Access Internal Constructor 'CollisionForm' here.

Comment: Did you write the CollsionForm or was it generated ?

Comment: It is provided by the vendor.  I cant change it.  Setting it to null works, but I was always told returning a null is just bad.  But I guess if that is all you can do. . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set it equal to null:

```
CollisionForm collision = null;
```

Make sure the returning code accepts `null` as a valid return value of course. The compiler just wants to make sure *some* value is assigned to the variable before using it.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.  Cant accept you answer for another 8 minutes it says.

Comment: @SDanks No worries; glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: Maybe this "CollisionForm collision = new CollisionForm();" could provide the same result?

Comment: @MiKE That would be a very different result. Regardless, that doesn't work per the OP's post.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mike, but adding the () didnt help either.  It is evidently an internal definition in a dll provided by the vendor but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you have made the constructor of  the colisionclass internal or private  you are going to have to make a public method that returns a instance of colisionclass

Comment: Actually it is in a dll provided by a vendor so I cant change it.  Just wondered if there was a way to instantiate the variable as empty.